# Obter expressão equivalente a list(zip(lista, heights)) usando a função map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, programação-funcional

Sejam:

```
heights = [x*0.0254 for x in [69,77,54]]
lista = [69,77,54]
```

A expressão:

```
print(list(zip(lista,heights)))
```

tem como saída:

```
[(69, 1.7526), (77, 1.9558), (54, 1.3716)]
```

Meu objetivo é obter a mesma saída mas utilizando a função `map()`:

Eu tentei fazer:

```
print(list(map(lambda x,y:zip(x,y),lista,heights)))
```

mas estou obtendo o erro:

```
print(list(map(lambda x,y:zip(x,y),lista,heights)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

O que estou fazendo errado? Como corrigir a expressão usando `map()` de forma a obter a mesma saída abaixo?

```
[(69, 1.7526), (77, 1.9558), (54, 1.3716)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está no `zip(x,y)`. O que a função `zip()` faz é, para cada elemento da lista x , junta com o elemento correspondente em posição da lista y em uma tupla e a adiciona a uma lista. Ou seja, essa função espera como parâmetros objetos iteráveis, como listas por exeplo.

A função `map()` executa uma função especificada para cada item em um iterável. O item é enviado para a função como um parâmetro.

Na prática, o que vc está fazendo é passar para a sua função `zip()` os valores `69` e `1.7526`, que não são iteráveis, por ser inteiro e float. Por isso que aparece o erro:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Ou seja, um objeto do tipo `int` não é iterável.

Quebrando o problema por partes, temos:

```
def myFunc(x,y):
  return (x,y) 

>>> print(list(map(myFunc, [69,77,54], [1.7526, 1.9558, 1.3716])))
    [(69, 1.7526), (77, 1.9558), (54, 1.3716)]
```

A ideia de usar o `lambda` é que ele entra como a função, então em vez de declarar uma função `myFunc`, posso usar direto `lambda x,y: (x,y)`:

```
>>> print(list(map(lambda x,y: (x,y), [69,77,54], [1.7526, 1.9558, 1.3716])))
    [(69, 1.7526), (77, 1.9558), (54, 1.3716)]
```

Mas também é possível deixar mais automático ainda:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: (x, x*0.0254),[69,77,54])))
```